# Type or namespace name Mock<> could not be found Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq, dbcontext

I am trying to mock my `DbContext` for writing my unit tests.

I saw a tutorial, and tried to do it like the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyFirstTest()
{
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<VMStored>>();
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Type or namespace name Mock<> could not be found

I am using EF 6. I know this is something simple but I didn't find any answer online regarding this issue.

I don't know what assembly if needed I need to add or what package to install.

I did everything they said in the MSDN tutorial, including update my code in the `.Context.tt` file of the following function:

```
public string DbSet(EntitySet entitySet)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} virtual DbSet<{1}> {2} {{ get; set; }}",
        Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet),
        _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entitySet.ElementType),
        _code.Escape(entitySet));
}
```

Any ideas what I need to do?

Comment: Do you have a project reference and a "using" statement for Moq?

Comment: One possible source to get moq: [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/)

Comment: Read the rest of the exception message.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to the Nuget Package Manager (right click project or solution in Solution Manager) and search for Moq. You're just missing the libraries.